# Can multiple Entity Framework Data Contexts be used within a single TransactionScope?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, transactionscope

I'm attempting to use multiple EntityFramework 6 DataContexts in a TransactionScope using{}.

I get the following Exception

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: The underlying provider failed on Open.

Inner Exception 1

> Network access for Distributed Transaction Manager (MSDTC) has been disabled.
>
> Please enable DTC for network access in the security configuration for MSDTC using the Component Services Administrative tool.

Inner Exception 2

> The transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions.
>
> (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004D024)

The code works fine without the TransactionScope.

Here are the questions I need answered:

**What is the best way to apply transactions to two datacontexts being used at the same time? What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: what version of .NET?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Do the contexts address different databases?

Comment: Different databases and also different servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not EF that's stopping you, but DTC.  DTC is needed when using two or more simultaneous connections to MSSQL.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd327979.aspx

ps. Duplicate of [MSDTC issue with transactions in ADO.NET Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611950/msdtc-problem-with-transactions-in-ado-net-entity-framework?rq=1)

Comment: I had tried this before asking the question and did it wrong originally. I tried it again today and it solves the problem. Thank you for your answer!