# transaction problem with entity framework 4

Tags: entity-framework, msdtc

I'm trying to implement a transaction with entity framework 4.  From what I've read, the code below is correct.  The SaveChanges works fine but as soon as I hit the first ExecuteFunction call I get the following exception:

> The underlying provider failed on
>   Open. --->
>   System.Transactions.TransactionManagerCommunicationException:
>   Network access for Distributed
>   Transaction Manager (MSDTC) has been
>   disabled. Please enable DTC for
>   network access in the security
>   configuration for MSDTC using the
>   Component Services Administrative
>   tool.

I've logged on to the database server and I don't see a service called Distributed Transaction Manager but I do see Distributed Transaction Coordinator and it is started.  I'm not sure what I need to change to allow this to work.  Anyone know?  Thanks.

Here's the code.

```
using (var h = new WhaleEntities(ConnectionHelper.DBConnectString))
{
    using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
    {
        h.Sites.AddObject(s);
        h.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.DetectChangesBeforeSave); 
        retval = s.SiteID;

        h.ExecuteFunction("UpdateSiteInterfaceList", new ObjectParameter("pSiteID", retval), new ObjectParameter("pList", "10"));
        h.ExecuteFunction("UpdateSiteInterfaceRequiredList", new ObjectParameter("pSiteID", retval),new ObjectParameter("pList", "Email"));
        h.ExecuteFunction("UpdateSiteInterfaceAlwaysShownList", new ObjectParameter("pSiteID", retval),new ObjectParameter("pList", "10"));
        h.ExecuteFunction("UpdateSiteInterfaceAlwaysRequiredList",new ObjectParameter("pSiteID", retval),new ObjectParameter("pList", "Email"));

        ts.Complete();

        //changes must be accepted manually once transaction succeeds.
        h.AcceptAllChanges();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here: [How do I enable MSDTC on SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694/how-do-i-enable-mstdc-on-sqlserver)