# MVC 3 : The MSDTC transaction manager was unable to pull the transaction from the source

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, msdtc

I am using MVC 3 with Entities, now I have used the below line of codes from my controller

```
        using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            _myRepository.DeleteFM1(id);
            _myRepository.DeleteFM2(id, name);
            scope.Complete();
        }
```

and inside my **DeleteFM2** method which happens to be my method defined in the Entity class is as follows :

```
    public void DeleteFM2(int id, string name)
    {
        var data= _repositoryMD.Fetch().Where(mColl => mColl.Col1 == id);

        if (data!= null)
        {
                //insert here is giving some error MSDTC error !
                // here I prepare a message using the '**data**'
                _repositoryHistory.Insert(name, message, "FM2", "Delete", dateTime);


                _repositoryMD.Attach(data);
                _repositoryMD.Delete(data);
                _repositoryMD.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
```

and I have a seperate class where I have defined the Insert method as

```
   public bool Insert(string realName, string logMessage, string tableName, string changeType, DateTime dateTime)
    {
        var history = new History
        {
            ModifiedBy = realName,
            ChangeType = changeType,
            DateModified = dateTime,
            LogMessage = logMessage,
            TableName = tableName
        };

        _repositoryHistory.Add(history);
        _repositoryHistory.SaveChanges();

        return true;
    }
```

After inserting this line of code in the above method DeleteFM2

```
      _repositoryHistory.Insert(name, message, "FM2", "Delete", dateTime);
```

I am getting this error, without this line my code works just fine, I have used this line in all of my other methods too even where I there I had used Transaction Scope, but I still dont seem to understand the problem here. Please help. Thanks

**The underlying provider failed on Open.**

> System.Transactions.TransactionManagerCommunicationException:
> Communication with the underlying transaction manager has failed. --->
> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The MSDTC transaction
> manager was unable to pull the transaction from the source transaction
> manager due to communication problems. Possible causes are: a firewall
> is present and it doesn't have an exception for the MSDTC process, the
> two machines cannot find each other by their NetBIOS names, or the
> support for network transactions is not enabled for one of the two
> transaction managers. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004D02B) at
> System.Transactions.Oletx.IDtcProxyShimFactory.ReceiveTransaction(UInt32
> propgationTokenSize, Byte[] propgationToken, IntPtr managedIdentifier,
> Guid& transactionIdentifier, OletxTransactionIsolationLevel&
> isolationLevel, ITransactionShim& transactionShim) at
> System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.GetOletxTransactionFromTransmitterPropigationToken(Byte[]
> propagationToken) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at
> System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.GetOletxTransactionFromTransmitterPropigationToken(Byte[]
> propagationToken) at
> System.Transactions.TransactionStatePSPEOperation.PSPEPromote(InternalTransaction
> tx) at
> System.Transactions.TransactionStateDelegatedBase.EnterState(InternalTransaction
> tx) at
> System.Transactions.EnlistableStates.Promote(InternalTransaction tx)
> at System.Transactions.Transaction.Promote() at
> System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.ConvertToOletxTransaction(Transaction
> transaction) at
> System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.GetExportCookie(Transaction
> transaction, Byte[] whereabouts) at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.GetTransactionCookie(Transaction
> transaction, Byte[] whereAbouts) at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.EnlistNonNull(Transaction
> tx) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.Enlist(Transaction
> tx) at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.Activate(Transaction
> transaction) at
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.ActivateConnection(Transaction
> transaction) at
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection
> owningObject) at
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection
> owningConnection) at
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection
> outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() at
> System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.OpenStoreConnectionIf(Boolean
> openCondition, DbConnection storeConnectionToOpen, DbConnection
> originalConnection, String exceptionCode, String attemptedOperation,
> Boolean& closeStoreConnectionOnFailure)

[image: My FireWall settings]

My FireWall settings

Comment: are the two repositories' databases on the same server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error implies that MSDTC is either not running on the database server that contains the database which `_repositoryHistory` targets; or that there is a network issue preventing propagation of the transaction to that machine.

Check that MSDTC is installed and running on the database server.

Check whether Windows Firewall is running on the target server; if it is, check the firewall exclusions for MSDTC.  This link helps with that: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725913(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: I have followed your advice (see updated screenshot in question) , I am using this _repositoryHistory in many different places this is actually for logging whenever there is an update/insert/delete. I have used it in more than 50 other places and it works fine there, I have even used it in the same class as where this DeleteFM2() method is. It doesnt work only for that.

Comment: and it's always in conjunction with using `_repositoryMD`?  MSDTC communication must be able to work between the servers those two databases are on as well

Comment: take out the call to `DeleteFM1` - does `DeleteFM2` work then?

Comment: Try changing a setting or restarting DTC on the database server. Worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer? The comments seem to indicate that the issue was not resolved so if it was, perhaps someone could tell how? Thanks!

Comment: @sirdank I guess the truth is there are often so many reasons why distributed transactions don't work.  Most commonly it's simply a case of it not being installed or being blocked by the firewall.  However, as highlighted by JeremyWeir's excellent answer, even once it's set up there are other things that can go wrong.  Indeed, in this age of virtual machines often being cloned in the 'wrong' way, I'd suggest a lot of people encounter the problem he describes there.  Meanwhile, wonster suggests using DTCPing to diagnose: that's very good advice ;)

Answer (score 16):

I also encountered this error even though the config, firewalls and netbios/dns were set up correctly. The two servers in my setup were clones of one another, so MSDTC on each server had the same CID value, which makes them not able to interoperate.

Here are some other things to think about when troubleshooting MSDTC
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561924.aspx
My situation is described under **Ensure that MSDTC is assigned a unique CID value**

> The MSDTC feature of the Windows operating system requires unique CID
>   values to ensure that MSDTC functionality between computers works
>   correctly. Disk duplicate images of Windows installations must have
>   unique CID values or MSDTC functionality may be impaired. This can
>   occur when using virtual hard disks to deploy an operating system to a
>   virtual machine.
>
> To determine if MSDTC CID values for computers that are running the
>   Windows operating system are unique, check the values for the entries
>   under the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CID registry key on both computers. If
>   these values are not unique for each computer then follow the steps in
>   the section Consider reinstalling the Distributed Transaction
>   Coordinator service if other troubleshooting steps are not successful
>   to reinstall MSDTC on one of the computers, which will then generate
>   unique MSDTC CID values for that computer and accommodate proper MSDTC
>   operations.

To reset the CIDs on a Windows 2012 Server use the following Powershell script:

```
#View: CIDs (These must be different on all systems)
ls Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CID | select Name


#reinstall MSDTC to regenerate CIDs. 
msdtc -uninstall
sleep 5
msdtc -install
sleep 5
Set-Service msdtc -startuptype "auto"
#then reboot for changes to take effect
```

Comment: Did it, same problem persists

Comment: It fixed my problem. DTCPing said clearly "Duplicated CID"

Comment: Just commenting to say, this saved my day today, in 2020 :)

Answer (score 5):

Use [DTCPing](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918331) to troubleshoot DTC related errors. This has been the go to tool for me for many years to troubleshoot distributed transaction writes in our system.

Comment: Cannot recommend this utility enough!

Comment: Agree totally. DTCPing allowed me to see that CID was duplicated

Answer (score 2):

After trying everything else here, I had to add the DTC Service (MSDTC.EXE) to my firewall.
The default firewall settings for the **"Distributed Transaction Coordinator"** was using `"%SystemRoot%\system32\svchost.exe"`.
Adding a new rule with *MSDTC.EXE* fixed the issues.

Comment: If it is a continuation to some existing answer then, it is better edit the post & put this information rather than posting as a different answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem now for a couple weeks. We have two web servers (Win 2012) and one DB server (Win 2008). Turns out that enabling the "no authentication" option for security solved our problem.

CIDs : all different on each server
MSDTC Network Access : Enabled
MSDTC Remote Access : Enabled
MSDTC Remote Admin : Disabled
MSDTC No Authentication : Enabled

Now it works properly in the server farm.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and in my case the issue was resolved when enabled No Authentication in MSDTC settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Recycle the application pool of the given MVC web application. I have experienced this issue, and found this to help immediately.