# inserting to a local table from a linked stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, linked-server

I have a sproc that is called from .net code which does an update on a local table and then is supposed to insert to a different local table values that are obtained from a remote procedure call to a linked server.

I get this error message every time I try to insert the results from the linked server.  If i take out the insert into statement, but leave the remote procedure call in place, it works fine.  Here is the error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The operation could not be
>   performed because OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server
>   "MyLinkedServer" was unable to begin a distributed transaction. OLE DB
>   provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked server "MyLinkedServer" returned
>   message "The transaction manager has disabled its support for
>   remote/network transactions.".

this is the simple code I'm using:

```
INSERT INTO MyLocalTable
EXEC [MyLinkedServer].[MyRemoteDatabase].[dbo].[usp_MySproc] @MyParam
```

any ideas what's wrong here or any suggestions of how I can insert the results from the remote procedure to a local table?

Comment: Is your 'distributed Transaction Coordinator' Service Started?

Comment: I'm not sure.  which server would that need to be started on?  The remote one or the local one?  In either case, I won't have access to that.  That would be a different team (DBA team) and they're not keen on doing admin stuff like that.  Is there another way to get the data remotely and save it locally?

Comment: IIRC, the DTC service needs to be started on both the client, and server machine.

Comment: I just asked the dba guys...that service is started and running on both machines...any other ideas?

Comment: Your error message says "The transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network transactions."  At this point you would probably want to have the DBA/IT guys check the configurations of the DTC to see if they allow remote connections, which the error message leads me to believe it is not

Comment: well, as I said in my OP, I can call the remote sproc w/o any issues.  It's only when I add the INSERT INTO statement above the remote procedure call that I run into this problem.  I could (I guess), just call the remote sproc, fill an object in code, then pass that object back to sql to fill the table, but that seems unnecessary....surely there's a way to do all of this with just sql?

Comment: I think these guys discussed in pretty much detail:    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694/how-do-i-enable-msdtc-on-sql-server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one of the sql guys was able to resolve this by changing the "enable promotion of distributed transactions" to false.