# 2 SQL different database updates in one .NET transaction

Tags: c#, sql, .net, transactions, msdtc

```
 TransactionOptions options = new TransactionOptions();
 options.IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
 options.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0);
 using (TransactionScope scope = new  TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, options))                    
 {
     try
     {
           Update to Database One;
           Update to Database Two;
           scope.Complete();    
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         scope.Dispose();
         throw;                            
     }
}
```

I have two SQL updates that I need to do in .NET transaction. The above code is giving me the error:

> "Network access for Distributed Transaction Manager (MSDTC) has been
>   disabled. Please enable DTC for network access in the security
>   configuration for MSDTC using the Component Services Administrative
>   tool."

DTC is enabled on both the servers where the databases are installed.
Please guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Why don't you use stored procedure to run 2 queries then execute it in your code?

Comment: Is MSDTC enabled on server where code is running?

Comment: @Dan it is located in two different servers and I cannot have a transaction and use linked servers

Comment: @Backs: I will look into that and see if it is enabled. thank you for pointing out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I enable MSDTC on SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694/how-do-i-enable-msdtc-on-sql-server)

Comment: FYI, `TransactionScope`, if used with `using`, will automatically Dispose and rollback if things fail.  You don't need the Try/Catch as shown in your example, just the 2 updates and the `Complete`.