# TransactionScope and method call that uses the same connection

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, transactions, ado.net, transactionscope

I'm using [`TransactionScope`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) to make a method that contains multiple sql statements transactional.  Now i need to call a second method that also uses the same connection and i receive following exception at `connection.Open()`:

> Network access for Distributed Transaction Manager (MSDTC) has been
>   disabled. Please enable DTC for network access in the security
>   configuration for MSDTC using the Component Services Administrative
>   tool.

So this is the pseudo-code:

```
public static void Method1()
{
    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        bool success = true; // will be set to false in an omitted catch
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString1))
        {
           // ...
           if(somethingHappened)
               Method2();
        }
        if(success)
            scope.Complete();
    }
}

public static void Method2()
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString1))
    {
        connection.Open(); // BOOOM!
        // ...
    }
}
```

How to avoid this exception without repeating the code from `Method2` in `Method1`?

Comment: I got this too, but on different connectionstrings.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694/how-do-i-enable-msdtc-on-sql-server, check if the answer with 64 upvotes helps

Comment: @Steve, This error on different connectionstrings is expected behavior

Comment: @mybirthname: if possible i want to avoid using MSDTC because it's unneeded overhead. If i understand it correctly  DTC needs to be used only when more than one physical computer is going to be involved in a distributed transaction. This is not the case, it's the same database on the same server, actually it's the same connection string.

Comment: If more then one connections are open in same time it will automatically escalate to the DTC - but not sure about version of Sql Server

Comment: @Fabio: so what is your suggestion, to pass the connection to Method2? That's ugly because it's a public method.

Comment: I prefer to use own connection for every query - so my suggestion: execute command with connection1, then close it, then open connection2 with method2

Comment: @fabio: ok, so first `Complete` the `TransactionScope` and then call `Method2`. But then i don't include it in my transaction. Since that is updating the database too it would be nice if it could be run in the same transaction.

Comment: All method/queries executed under same TransactionScope will be executed as one trasaction

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128620/discussion-between-fabio-and-tim-schmelter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If more then one connection are open under same `TransactionScope` it will be automatically escalated to the DTC.

You need to close first connection before calling `Method2`.

```
public static void Method1()
{
    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        bool success = true; // will be set to false in an omitted catch

        bool isSomethingHappened
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString1))
        {
           isSomethingHappened = // Execute query 1
        }

       if(somethingHappened)
           Method2();

        if(success)
            scope.Complete();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah. The question was about the same connection *string*, not the same connection :/

Answer (score 2):

Nested connections under the same transaction scope will promote to a distributed transaction.

From SQL server 2008 and above multiple (not nesting) connections under the same transaction scope will not promote to a distributed transaciton.

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690892/transactionscope-automatically-escalating-to-msdtc-on-some-machines) question for more information

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the precise answer, but I would make the connection a member, and keep track if it's open.

Then in Method1 and Method2 I would get the connection via some GetConnection() which would open the connection on first use.

---

After reading the comments I would suggest a private DoMethod2 which takes in a connection object.