# Cannot open two SqlConnections inside a TransactionScope on Windows 10

Tags: c#, transactionscope, sqlconnection

When I try to open two different **SqlConnections** inside a **TransactionScope** on **Windows 10**, I got an exception on the opening of the second connection.

The same code on a **Windows Server 2016** works fine.

This error happened this week 2018-11-23 (I suspect a windows update)

Exception details: **System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException**: 'Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.'

Code sample :

```cs
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Transactions;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
            {
                using (var connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost,1433;Initial Catalog=DataAccessIntegrationTests;User Id=MyUser;Password=MyPassword;"))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    using (var connection2 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost,1433;Initial Catalog=DataAccessIntegrationTests;User Id=MyUser;Password=MyPassword;"))
                    {
                        connection2.Open();
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Everything is ok...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Both use the same connection-string

Comment: what database server version is this? I'm wondering if this is a LTM vs DTC problem...

Comment: @TimSchmelter you can create multiple connections to one server with the same connection string... nothing wrong or even unusual there... (unless the server is in single-user-mode, of course)

Comment: @MarcGravell: i just remembered i had a related(?) question some time ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40719155/transactionscope-and-method-call-that-uses-the-same-connection

Comment: @MarcGravell This happen on SQL Server 2017 and SQL Server 2016